# Email Data Annotation not working in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, data-annotations

So this is my Model :

```
[Display(Name = "*Email")]
[EmailAddress]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

And the View :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

While the Email validation works mostly fine, it does not catch if '.'(dot) is not present. So test@gmailcom is considered valid. Anyway to fix it?

Comment: Write your own `RegularExpression`?

Comment: Hello,is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use RegularExpressionAttribute to replace EmailAddressAttribute.Here is a working demo:

Model :

```
[Display(Name = "*Email")]
[RegularExpression(@"^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$",ErrorMessage ="The Email field is not a valid e-mail address.")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

result:
[image]